# CSSTransitionGroup component doesn't leave properly

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reactcsstransitiongroup, react-transition-group

I'm trying to create a modal for logging in with a mask that fades in when you click login button and fades out when you close it. I decided to us 'react-transition-group' library for implementing that. Fading in works fine, but it fades out right away, without the animation being applied. How can I make it work?

Connected component:

```
<div>
                <ModalRoot {...this.props}>
                    <Grid>
                        <Menu {...this.props}/>
                        <div className='wrapper'>
                            <div className='content'>
                                <Form postTodo={this.props.postTodo}/>
                                <ul className='todo-list'>
                                   <CSSTransitionGroup
                                    transitionName='todo'
                                    transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                                    transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
                                        {todoItems}
                                    </CSSTransitionGroup>    
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Grid>
                </ModalRoot> 
            </div>
```

ModalRoot:

```
const MODAL_COMPONENTS = {
  LOGIN_MODAL: LoginModal,
  /* other modals */
};

const ModalRoot = (props: any) => {
    const {isVisible, isMaskShown, window} = props.modal;
    const Modal = MODAL_COMPONENTS[window];
    if(!isVisible) {
      return (
        <div>
          {props.children}
        </div>
      );
    }
    if(isMaskShown) {
      return (
        <CSSTransitionGroup
          transitionName='mask'
          transitionAppear={true}
          transitionAppearTimeout={500}
          transitionEnterTimeout={0}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
            <Mask>
              <Modal key={100} hideModal={props.hideModal} />
                {props.children}
            </Mask>
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
      );
    }
    if(!isMaskShown) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Modal hideModal={props.hideModal}/>
          {props.children}
        </div>  
      );
    }
};
```

LoginModal:

```
const LoginModal = ({hideModal,presets}) => {

    return (
        <div className='login-modal'>
            <button onClick={hideModal} className='close'>X</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

CSS:

```
 .mask {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

.mask-leave {
  opacity: 0.75;
}  

.mask-leave.mask-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}

.mask-appear {
  opacity: 0;
}

.mask-appear.mask-appear-active {
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: What component are you trying to animate an "appear" and "leaving" transition for? In other words, what child component are you trying to mount and unmount?

Comment: I'm trying to mount and unmount <Mask/> component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<CSSTransitionGroup>` only handles animating the mounting and unmounting of components *that are children of the `<CSSTransitionGroup>` component*. You aren't supposed to mount or unmount the `<CSSTransitionGroup>` itself, you're supposed to mount or unmount its children.

The reason that it fades in but doesn't fade out is because you've specified the prop `transitionAppear={true}`, which causes `<CSSTransitionGroup>` to render an "appear" animation when it first mounts. But, when your `isMaskShown` variable goes from `true` to `false`, consider what happens inside of your render function: the `<CSSTransitionGroup>` is instantly unmounted, without a chance to animate a "leaving" transition, because - once again - `<CSSTransitionGroup>` only animates *components that are directly inside of it*.

The solution is to mount your `<CSSTransitionGroup>` only once, keep it static, and only conditionally render its children. It's hard to tell from your code what component you are trying to animate in and out, so I can't give you a direct solution. But keep in mind my explanation and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem here. I decided to wrap everything in <ModalRoot/> component in order to be able to put a mask on all my content, but I don't see how I can make it work with the structure I have. Do you have any ideas how to make it work so I'll be able to conditionally mount modals either with a mask or without it? Seems like I need to put <ModalRoot /> somewhere else.

Comment: If I didn't need a mask I would do something like this https://codepen.io/NoOneKnowsWhoIam/pen/YxPbJe, but as you can see the mask doesn't cover all the content. Maybe there is a way to put a mask with this structure and I just need to do something about my CSS?

Comment: @Umbrella If the mask is a simple layer for covering background content underneath the modal, then there is no need for the modal to be _inside_ of the mask. Make them separate so that you can mount or unmount either without affecting the other.